# Sorting Map/TreeMap/LinkedHashMap by Value (custom data structures)

Tags: sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am currently having some issues in trying to sort a `Map<String, IncreaseDetails>`, where `IncreaseDetails` is simply a custom data structure holding a few fields.

So far I have understood fairly clearly that using a `TreeMap` is heavily discouraged as a TreeMap should be sorted by the KeySet rather than the actual values.

I have therefore tried to switch to both `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` but simply calling

`Collections.sort(map,comparator)` doesn't seem to do the trick. Since Java 8 I was planning on trying to use the Stream API, but I don't really know it too well.

So far my comparator looks like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

public class CompTool implements Comparator<Float> {

    Map<String, IncreaseDetails> unsortedMap;

    public CompTool(Map<String, IncreaseDetails> unsortedMap)
    {
        this.unsortedMap = unsortedMap;
    }

    public int compare(Float countryOne, Float countryTwo)
    {
        Float countryOneValue = unsortedMap.get(countryOne).getRealIncrease();
        Float countryTwoValue = unsortedMap.get(countryTwo).getRealIncrease();
        return countryTwoValue.compareTo(countryOneValue);
    }

}
```

Any suggestion would be very much welcome, as I have found a lot of similar questions or videos but none too useful for my current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear. I assume that you want to sort the `unsortedMap` entries by the value stored in `getRealIncrease` in reversed order. This can be done by creating the stream of original map entries, sorting and collecting the result into the `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves insertion order:

```
Map<String, IncreaseDetails> sortedMap = unsortedMap.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                (Comparator.comparing(IncreaseDetails::getRealIncrease).reversed())))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> a,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't too clear. But anyway, yes that is what I was looking for.

Thank you so much.